# How to create a trigger function in firebase that sends notification to android when the node reaches a particular value?

Tags: android, firebase

Hi guys I'm developing a app that needs a push notification from firebase when the node at firebase changes to particular value (***say like if it reaches 100, then it needs to trigger a notification to android***).

And how could I possibly do that?
I know if there is change in node there will be a notification but I don't want that I just wanna send 4 notification for 100values changes in node, so how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're using cloud funtions?

Comment: Yes but if it's any other way?

Comment: I think cloud functions is the best way because it consentrates things where they should be

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a listener to your reference

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() >= 100){
      //do something here
      //make notification
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and reply if there's any doubt